# Background Image filling and resizing to browser window

Tags: html, css, parallax

This is the effect I need for my website:

http://urban-walks.com/#nicer_way

Not the fancy side of it - I have background images for certain 'sections' or divs, and I need them to fill the whole of the browser window. They also need to resize when changing browser side (such as using mobile) so it keeps the effect.

This is my current code for each div -

HTML:

```
<div class="graph">
    <br><h1>Latest SKE Graph</h1>
    <img src="knowledge_graph.jpg">  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.graph {
background-image: url("pexels-photo-279366.jpeg");
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 700px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Use % or  `vh` and `vw` units to size the elements that need to scale to the window size.

Comment: Did you try to set the position absolute; top 0; left 0; ?

Comment: thanks - sorry, I'm really new to web development. can you explain what would need changing and how I can use those units please?

Comment: @Bibimission thanks but no luck, that made my div go all the way to the top left corner and go skinny and tall

Comment: add width 100% and height 100%

Comment: Just change height to 100%. Don't give a width value unless you want the image to get distorted

Comment: which image you're trying to make as background the `knowledge_graph.jpg` or the `pexels-photo-279366.jpeg` ?

Comment: @Bibimission but my div is in between other divs, so it's just squashed the one below it - had to take away the top/left; 0 as it was putting the div at the top of the page

Comment: @Adam the latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your height to "100vh" and your width to "100vw". v stands for view-port of the device.

```
 .graph {
background-image: url("pexels-photo-279366.jpeg");
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
text-align: center;
```

}

Comment: Perfect - that's exactly what I was after! Much appreciated :)